# How to handle the bounding rect clicking of QPainter

Tags: c++, qt

[image]

Now I draw my custom widget by using QPainterPath and rotate technique, code snippet is listed here:

```
QRectF flowerBanRect(-radius + (-width / 2), -radius + (-margin) + (-height), width, height);
QPainterPath flowerPath;
flowerPath.moveTo(-radius + (-width / 4), -diameter + (-margin));
flowerPath.lineTo(-radius + width / 4, -diameter + (-margin));
flowerPath.lineTo(-radius + width / 2, -diameter + (-margin) + (-height));
flowerPath.lineTo(-radius + (-width / 2), -diameter + (-margin) + (-height));

QPainterPath diffPath = flowerPath - headPath;

painter->setBrush(QBrush(getReagentSeatColor(0)));
painter->fillPath(diffPath, QBrush(getReagentSeatColor(0)));
painter->drawText(flowerBanRect, Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignTop, QString("01"));
painter->save();

float degree = 360.0 / MAX_TRAY;
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TRAY - 1; ++i) {
    painter->rotate(degree);
    painter->setBrush(QBrush(getReagentSeatColor(i + 1)));
    painter->fillPath(diffPath, QBrush(getReagentSeatColor(i + 1)));
    painter->drawText(flowerBanRect, Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignTop, QString("%1").arg(i + 2, 2, 10, QChar('0')));
}
```

But now how I handle the **EVERY SECTOR** clicking.

Comment: As far as i understand, every sector is just a drawing on a widget you're implementing. If you don't want to change your current implementation, i suggest you override this widgets `mouseClickEvent` and calculate what sector did user click on. For that purpose you'll need some kind of container which would store all the sectors with it's positions (maybe a map, for example). When user clicks on widget, you calculate mouse click position in widget's local coordinates and retrieve the exact sector by calculated coordinate -  thats the sector that needs a redrawing.

Comment: Ofcourse, this seems like a very poor implementation and this isn't what i would recommend in a first place. You'll have a much better time writing your application if you use QGraphicsView with QGraphicsItems. In that case, you'll have QGraphicsView as an analog to your widget, but every sector would be a separate QGraphicsItem object, which you can easily adress and redraw by simply changing its pen or brush.

Comment: Now i rewrite with QGraphicsItem, BUT the mousePressEvent is not called at all.

Comment: i'm not able to help you without seeing what you've tried

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be to override the mousePressEvent of the QWidget in your class like this.

```
void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;
```

Then you call whatever function you want to get the position from the [QMouseEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmouseevent.html) doc, but I would recommend event->pos() because it returns the position relative to the widget you are calling it from. You can either calculate the positions of each sector at run time, or you can store them in a QList or QMap. Then compare the positions and figure out which sector the mouse is in.